# Z-coordinate in Jacobian coordinates

Tags: elliptic-curves, secp256k1

secp256k1 Generator:(G_X, G_Y, 0x1),

secp256k1 any public key using affine coordinates : B=(X, Y)

secp256k1 any Public key using jacobian coordinates:BB=(P_X, P_Y, P_Z)

(B's private key)==(BB's private key)

I consider <strike>projective</strike> Jacobian coordinates for secp256k1.

Given any public key B, if the z-coordinate after converting the generator of secp256k1 to Jacobian coordinates is set to  0x1, how should I calculate P_Z(the z-coordinate of any public key) without using scalar(private key) and a middle point?

Comment: If you just decoded a point, just set $Z$ to 1. If you're operating on a point, treat divisions on $X$ and $Y$ as multiplication on $Z$. Afterwards, if you encode a point, divide $Z$ from $X$ and $Y$ to get the encoded values. Is anything still unclear? or is it enough to make a formal answer?

Comment: @DannyNiu Careful! With [Jacobian coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic-curve_cryptography#Projective_coordinates) conversion to affine needs $X$ to be divided by $Z^2$ and $Y$ to be divided by $Z^3$.

Comment: For example, the final public key's Z-coordinate obtained from the generator point using jacobian-coordinates and the adding operator was different from the final public key's Z-coordinate obtained from the middle point using jacobian-coordinates and the adding operator. So, Setting the Z-coordinate of the generator point to 0x1 and setting the Z-coordinate of the middle point to 0x1 leads to different results....Z-coordinate

Comment: Note: I do not know "projective Jacobian coordinates", only Jacobian coordinates and the (different) projective coordinates.

Comment: https://www.hyperelliptic.org/EFD/g1p/auto-shortw-jacobian.html

Comment: @fgrieu I mean Jacobian coordinates

Comment: @kelalaka Thanks for the link info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall that a point (other than the point at infinity) on the [secp256k1](https://secp256k1) curve (or any [curve in Weierstrass form over a prime field $\mathbb F_p$](https://www.secg.org/sec1-v2.pdf#subsubsection.2.2.1)) having Cartesian coordinates $(X,Y)$ matches point with Jacobian coordinates $(x,y,z)$ if and only if $z^2\,X\equiv x\pmod p$ and $z^3\,Y\equiv y\pmod p$ and $z\not\equiv0\pmod p$. Notice that $z=0$ can be used to represent the point at infinity (otherwise said, the group's identity).

It follow that to convert $B=(X,Y)$ to Jacobian coordinates, we can use $BB=(X,Y,1)$.

Or, if we want some blinding for side-channel resistance, we can pick a random integer $z$ in $[1,p)$ and set $BB=\bigl((z^2\,X\bmod p),(z^3\,Y\bmod p),z\bigr)$.